# dynamically change wsdl by client's IP

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, cxf

I have an application which supports SOAP protocol.
In current implementation wsdl schemes are generated on-the fly when application is deployed. After that I provide the list of URLs of generated WSDLs of services to client(something like "http://myapp/services/").

The problem is that we have a specific service which has several methods which are restricted for clients by IP white-listing. So if client ip is in this white list, he should obtain WDSL which contains all service methods. If client's IP is not in white list, this client should obtain WSDL which contains only not-restricted service methods.

My assumption to solve this problem is **to keep two WSDLs for this service**:

1. the first contains all methods
2. the second contains only not restricted methods. This WSDL schema will be returned for clients which IPs are not in white-list

So the questions are: how to configure application with requirements above? Which way I can switch from first to second WSDL when I check client's IP?

Comment: When application is deployed, you can't change WSDL. Why don't you deploy both WSDLs? under slightly different names? Something like `../services.wsdl` and `../services-free.wsdl` and then you could redirect your client to one of these wsdls based on the IP. Mind you it's just an idea. Well, as for `how to configure`, those are wrong questions to ask.

Comment: yes, I agree with you that deploy 2 wsdl-s is a good idea. 
Client access WSDL's services url's list by calling  "http://myapp/services/"

and I still don't know now I can dynamically replace  services.wsdl by services-free.wsdl if client's IP is not in white-list. Maybe, by creating some kind of interceptor?